# How to display data from a Google Cloud SQL database by making GET requests using Python?

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform

I have to display data from a SQL database using App Engine from Google Cloud via Python.
All requests are GET type.
The package must also be imported into the Python file: `import requests`.
I also need to import the json package from the flask.
The application package will be used inside the "app.route" functions; I can define multiple routes (one for each URI above) in which I take and display the data; example full:

```
def employees():
    res = requests.get('https://ultra-automata-237814.appspot.com/employees')
    return app.response_class(
response=json.dumps(res.json()),
status=200,
mimetype='application/json'
)
```

I run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command.
I installed `requirements.txt` from my project root.
I upgraded pip.

Comment: The first step: read the Cloud SQL documentation plus SQL documentation. You need to use a client library and unless you want to reinvent the wheel, you will not be making raw REST requests. You will be interfacing with the database, which you did not specify, and you must meet its client programming requirements.

Comment: Unless it is homework in Python 101 and he has to use requests and Flask ;)

Comment: @JohnHanley and Joe thank you for your answers . Could you give me a better documentation for requests and Flask?

Comment: Go to the Flask website. They have excellent documentation.

Comment: @Joe - To recreate a SQL client library? That would be an interesting project and probably way above Python 101.

Comment: @john-hanley, I meant the GET requests :)